# helm templating add empty line when using nindent

Tags: templates, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

My `deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      {{- include "pod" . | nindent 6 }}
```

My `_pod.tpl`:

```yaml
{{- define "pod" -}}
{{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
imagePullSecrets:
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 2 }}
{{- end }}
serviceAccountName: foo
containers:
  - name: foo
    image: nginx:latest
{{- end }}
```

Give me:

```yaml
# Source: foo/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: bar
      serviceAccountName: foo
      containers:
        - name: foo
          image: nginx:latest
```

Why is there an empty line after `spec:`?

**Edited**

However, there is no empty line when using `{{- include "pod" . | indent 6 }}` in the Deployment, but there is 6 whitespaces after `spec:`, like that: `spec:`      .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The nindent function is the same as the indent function, but prepends
> a new line to the beginning of the string.

refer : https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#nindent

You should use `indent` instead of `nindent`, to avoid new line after `spec:`

Comment: Thanks! But according to this documentation: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#controlling-whitespace, in my `_pod.tpl`, all templating functions starting with a dash should remove all withespaces and newlines, no? I edited my post to add a problem with `indent`.

Comment: yes, you are right. But here, there are 2 new lines generated from this `{{- include "pod" . | nindent 6 }}`. One is from {{ }} and another from nindent. Either you need to use `trim` with nindent or simply use indent.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. The first newline (due to `{{ }}`) is removed because of the dash, so there is only one newline, no ? Or could you tell me why there are 6 whitespaces when using `indent` ?

Comment: In helm templating (which uses Go templating), `{{-` this will chop any trailing whitespace (bear in mind that Newlines are whitespace too) from your *include* statement, result in pasting your tpl right after `spec:` which apparently indent 6 whitespaces. In your case, it’s better to avoid `{{-` and use `{{ include "pod" . | indent 6 | trim }}` instead. @Antoine